# Are there any online tools for replacing single quote to double quote in invalid JSON or any solution to use the invalid json in PHP?

Tags: php, json, single-quotes

I have so many invliad JSON files.

This is the snippet of the invalid JSON file.

```
[
    {
    'name':'Arden',
    'born':'1973-12-22',
    'orientation':'Heterosexual',
    'purpose':'Friendship',
    'tags':'cooking,swimming,adventure,drawing',
    'country':'United Kingdom::Edinburgh',
    'about':'I often read (and enjoy!) things that are completely opposed to everything I believe. I've enjoyed.'
    },

    {
    'name':'Sisera',
    'born':'1962-01-25',
    'orientation':'Homosexual',
    'purpose':'Flirt',
    'tags':'reading,fishing,tennis,theater',
    'country':'United States::Fairfield',
    'about':'I'm OCD about shoes being placed side-by-side. I don't like them together by the door.'
    }
]
```

How can I replace this single quote to double quote?
Are there any online tools or any solution in PHP?

What I want is following:

```
[
    {
    "name":"Arden",
    "born":"1973-12-22",
    "orientation":"Heterosexual",
    "purpose":"Friendship",
    "tags":"cooking,swimming,adventure,drawing",
    "country":"United Kingdom::Edinburgh",
    "about":"I often read (and enjoy!) things that are completely opposed to everything I believe. I\'ve enjoyed."
    },

    {
    "name":"Sisera",
    "born":"1962-01-25",
    "orientation":"Homosexual",
    "purpose":"Flirt",
    "tags":"reading,fishing,tennis,theater",
    "country":"United States::Fairfield",
    "about":"I\'m OCD about shoes being placed side-by-side. I don\'t like them together by the door."
    }
]
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this

```
str_replace("'",'"',$jsonstring)
```

For an online tool, you can use this formatter
https://www.freeformatter.com/json-formatter.html#ad-output

As suggested by super for preg_replace. the code should be like this

```
preg_replace("/',/", '",', preg_replace("/':'/", '":"', preg_replace('/[ \t]+/', ' ', preg_replace("/[\r\n]+\s*[']\s*/", "\n\"", $jsonstring))));
```

Comment: Thank you. The online tool is cool, regex is not working.  And another issue is that the invalid json include single quote in there value, like this "can't, I'll, don't"

Comment: It doesn't work anyway, I've updated the invalid and valid json examples, can you please check it out?